# Pagination for JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, pagination

I have a large data set of quotes in JSON format e.g.

```
[
  {
    "Quote": "Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.",
    "Author": "Eleanor Roosevelt,  This is My Story",
    "Category": "wisdom"
  },
  {
    "Quote": "No one can make you feel inferior without your consent.",
    "Author": "Dr. Seuss",
    "Category": "life"
  },
  {
    "Quote": ""Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.",
    "Author": "Oscar Wilde",
    "Category": "inspiration"
  },
```

As it is a rather large data set, I would like to paginate it so that only 10 will be shown at a time. I came across the paginate.js plugin and tried to implement it into my code. I want to present these quotes along with the author and category to users of my website in a stylish manner (cards that expand on hover).

I am able to get and create the correct amount of entries/cards for the first page but the issue is that there doesn't seem to be any other page(s) or a navigator to get to the other quotes.

What my page looks like currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GgQA.png

As you can see from the image, the cards are created correctly, however, there isn't the pagination links to the other quotes, which I believe should be before the next div(little grey bit at the bottom of the image).

HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center px-md-2" id="quotes">
    <h4 class="pt-4">Quote Collection</h4>
    <section class="col-12 p-4 d-flex" id="card-list">
        <!-- Each card's markup looks like this from createQuoteCard() function from JS -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div id="category" class="text-center">
                    <span>
                        <p>Inspiration</p>
                    </span>
                    <img src="images/inspiration-quote.jfif" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>
                    "I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am
                    out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle
                    me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best."
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="author-name-prefix">Author</div>
                Marilyn Monroe
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card -->
    </section>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$("#card-list").pagination({
    dataSource: quotes,
    pageSize: 10,
    callback: function (data, pagination) {
      $("#card-list").empty();
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        const card = createQuoteCard(val.Quote, val.Author, val.Category); // function that creates the card markup
        $("#card-list").append(card);
      });
    },
  });
```

I expect there to be 3 pages as I am testing the pagination with 30 objects/cards. There isn't any errors and I can't find anything wrong with my code. Can anyone give me advice or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a runnable snippet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ajqfsyw/ @Razvan Zamfir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the event [afterRender](https://pagination.js.org/docs/index.html#afterRender) in order to move the pagination bar before the section card-list....so you can see it.

Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eakvLjf7/)

The function changed:

```js
function paginateQuotes(quotes) {
   let quoteCards = [];
   $("#card-list").pagination({
     dataSource: quotes,
     pageSize: 10,
      afterRender: function() {  // added this event
            if ($("#card-list div.paginationjs").length == 1) {
            $("#card-list div.paginationjs").insertBefore("#card-list")
        }
     },
     callback: function(data, pagination) {
       $("#card-list").empty();
       $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         const card = createQuoteCard(val.Quote, val.Author, val.Category); // funtion that creates the card markup
         $("#card-list").append(card);
       });
     },
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly with insertAfter() instead of insertBefore().